# Отобразить Push Notifications от MAUI приложения

Tags: c#, firebase, maui, push, fcm

```
private async void GetTokenClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await CrossFirebaseCloudMessaging.Current.CheckIfValidAsync();
        var token = await CrossFirebaseCloudMessaging.Current.GetTokenAsync();
        Token = token;
        await DisplayAlert("FCM token", token, "OK");
    }

private async void SendPushClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var app = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions
    {
        Credential = await GetCredential()
    });
    
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.GetMessaging(app);
    var message = new Message()
    {
        Token = Token,
        Notification = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Notification { Title = "Hello bro!", Body = "It's a message for Android with MAUI"},
        Data = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"greating", "hello"}},
        Android = new AndroidConfig { Priority = Priority.Normal},
        Apns = new ApnsConfig { Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { {"apns-priority", "5"}}}
    };
    var response = await messaging.SendAsync(message);


    
    await DisplayAlert("Response", response, "OK");
}
```

В переменной `response` находится ответ следующего формата: `projects/{project_id}/messages/{message_id}`

Что нужно сделать, чтобы отобразить данное уведомление у пользователя на телефоне как обычное уведомление.

Ремарка: когда я отправляю сообщение через FCM Console, то оно отображается отлично и всё приходит, но что нужно сделать внутри моего приложения, чтобы отобразить полученный `response`